# How to override Bootstrap css on Table element and attributes

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, attributes

I have a large `ASP.Net` app to which I am trying to add a `JQuery/Bootstrap` multiselect dropdown (can't add this to Fiddle - to large). I am using a Bootstrap CDN/API to add the multiselect and generic `Bootstrap css and js`. There is a table in my application. Before I added the Bootstrap, it looked like this.

[image]

After I add the bootstrap, it looks like this:

[image]

Basically, the `word-wrap: break-word;` attribute seems to be getting messed up. I have the Boostrap added before my custom css stylesheet as recommended by other posts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//js.arcgis.com/3.26/esri/css/esri.css?parameter=1"/> <%--"parameter= 1" prevents intellisense error --%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/Style/Style.css"/>
```

The table has its own id's for the element and children called `#checkBoxesTable`.

```
 #checkBoxesTable > tr > td {
     word-wrap: break-word;
 }
 ...
 .bootstrap-overrides #checkBoxesTable > tr > td {
     padding: 10px;
     word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

I've even tried to create a class (see above and below) to override any `Bootstrap` ids or classes but it doesn't seem to work (the table is dynamically created under the `scenarios` id in the `Default.asmx` file). Is there anything else I can try to get the `word-wrap` to work?:

```
<div id="scenarios" class="bootstrap-overrides"></div>
```

Comment: Does `white-space: nowrap` exist? If yes, change to `white-space: normal`'

Comment: Do you mean in the Bootstrap css? Since I am bringing the Bootstrap in through a cdn, should I just add that (white-space: normal)to the custom css?

Comment: Since you can't see the real `DOM`, I guess the reason for not wrapping is that `white-space` has been set to `nowrap`, which needs to be changed in the custom css.

Comment: Question: under what id/class/element would I add the css attribute `{white-space: normal}`? `id="scenarios"` ?

Comment: Just set it on the tag closest to the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, the problem here was the version of generic bootstrap I was using. I went to the multi-select `gitHub` documentation and looked in the index.html file for their example, which used the following:

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Once I upped the version to 3.3.2, it worked (with my override class of course).